# How to make WebLogic create sub-folder under server/logs directory?

Tags: log4j, weblogic

We all know that WebLogic server creates `logs` directory under `DOMAIN_HOME/servers/SERVER_NAME` directory at server start up. But now I want WebLogic to create my application specific logs directory like below at the server startup.

```
DOMAIN_HOME/servers/SERVER_NAME/logs/myAppLogs/
```

Where to do the configuration change for this?

Thank you,
Chaitanya

Comment: What do you mean by "application specific" logs? Are these logs generated by your application with a logging API e.g. log4j?

Comment: Yes. My application's logs are generated using log4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>See [Change server log file name and location](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/logging/ChangeServerLogFileNamesAndLocations.html) in the Administration Console Online Help.</strike>

**EDIT:** As per comment, the OP actually wants a file appender to create directories of parent-path if they don't exist. I don't know what versions of weblogic nor log4j are used but according to [9150](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9150), old versions of log4j don't implement this behavior:

> We can't assume log4j will have directory creation permissions, only write 
>   permissions to the file specified in the configuration.  It's up to the server 
>   administrator to control the directory tree.

This should be fixed in version 1.2.12 and later.

PS: I really prefer to find all logs in the same location on a single machine e.g. `/var/log/weblogic/<PROJECTNAME>/myApp-${weblogic.Name}.log`. It's really easier  to find the last file that changed, to `grep` log files, etc.

Comment: I want my applications logs generated using Log4J in particular location.How to do that?

Comment: Does your application have a log4j.properties or a log4j.xml configuration file? This is where it should be configured.

Comment: I use log4j.properties but in that I mention log file location as follows: 
log4j.appender.dailyRollingFile.File=servers/${weblogic.Name}/logs/myAppLogs/myApp.log

But I get the following exception:

log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: servers\ms1\logs\myAppLogs\myApp.log (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Thsi is because WebLogic does not create myAppLogs folder by itself. My initial question was to how to make WL create myAppLogs folder so that Log4J can create myApp.log in it. Hope I am clear.

Comment: Well, it's more clear now but 1. you should add these details to your question 2. I don't find it fair to downvote my answer because of your lack of clarity.

Comment: I am sorry. It will be reverted.Sorry again.

Comment: I am getting "Vote too old to be changed..." Will change it at appropriate time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below, this is use on the weblogic servers where weblogic.Name is default added on the java system properties on startup, mostly default on multiple weblogic managed nodes.

```
<param name="File" value="servers/${weblogic.Name}/logs/${weblogic.Name}-specific-name.log"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log4jconfig.xml file should be configured to generate the log file in your desired location. Sample param props in log4jconfg.xml file looks like this

```
<param name="File" value="DOMAIN_HOME/servers/SERVER_NAME/logs/myAppLogs/MyLog.txt"/>
<param name="Append" value="true"/>
<param name ="MaxFileSize" value="20480KB"/>
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p %c %x - %m%n"/>
```